# How can I find out how many blocks memory of each order is allocated by buddy allocator at the startup of the kernel?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

I know the way to find out how many free blocks are available on the current platform, e.g.:

```
sudo cat /proc/pagetypeinfo
Page block order: 9
Pages per block:  512

Free pages count per migrate type at order       0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10
Node    0, zone      DMA, type    Unmovable      0      1      1      0      2      1      1      0      1      0      0
Node    0, zone      DMA, type      Movable      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      3
Node    0, zone      DMA, type  Reclaimable      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone      DMA, type   HighAtomic      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone      DMA, type      Isolate      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone    DMA32, type    Unmovable      1      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      0
Node    0, zone    DMA32, type      Movable      3      4      5      4      2      3      4      4      1      2    730
Node    0, zone    DMA32, type  Reclaimable      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone    DMA32, type   HighAtomic      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone    DMA32, type      Isolate      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone   Normal, type    Unmovable     17      2      2      1      0      0      0      1      2     13      0
Node    0, zone   Normal, type      Movable     15      4      0     15      4      1      1      0      0      0    934
Node    0, zone   Normal, type  Reclaimable      0      6     21      9      6      3      3      1      2      0      0
Node    0, zone   Normal, type   HighAtomic      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
Node    0, zone   Normal, type      Isolate      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0

Number of blocks type     Unmovable      Movable  Reclaimable   HighAtomic      Isolate
Node 0, zone      DMA            1            7            0            0            0
Node 0, zone    DMA32            2         1526            0            0            0
Node 0, zone   Normal          160         2314           78            0            0
```

How can I find out how many blocks memory of each order is allocated by buddy allocator at the startup of the kernel?